# Distributed system simulator

Tags: python, simulation

I have coded a  very simple distributed system simulator in Python. It uses multiprocessing to assign tasks, and queues to communicate between processes.

The code is shown below.

```
from functions import *
import multiprocessing
import time

try:
    with open("config.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    max_instances =  int(lines[0].split(' ')[1])
except Exception, e:
    print "Exception while opening config.txt :", e
    print "Please make sure that\n1) The File is present in the current folder"
    print "2) It contains the value of MAX_NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES, space delimited"
    print "Download the file again if problem persists"
    exit(1)


class machine():
    'Class for the instance of a machine'

    q = [multiprocessing.Queue() for i in range(max_instances + 1)]
    # q[0] is unused
    count = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1)

    def __init__(self):
        self.mac_id = machine.count.value
        machine.count.value += 1

    def execute_func(self, func_name, *args):
        comm_str = str(func_name) + ' = multiprocessing.Process(name = "' + str(func_name) + '", target = ' + str(func_name) + ', args = ('
        comm_str += 'self,'
        for arg in args:
            if(type(arg) is str):
                comm_str += '"' + str(arg) + '",'
            else:
                comm_str += str(arg) + ','
        comm_str += '))'

        try:
            # create the new process
            exec(comm_str)

            # start the new process
            comm_str = str(func_name) + '.start()'
            exec(comm_str)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Exception in execute_func() of", self.get_machine_id(), ":", e
            print self.get_machine_id(), "was not able to run the function ", func_name
            print "Check your function name and parameters passed to execute_func() for", self.get_machine_id()


    def send(self, destination_id, message):
        # send message to the machine with machine_id destination_id

        mac_id = int(destination_id[8:])
        if(mac_id >= machine.count.value or mac_id <= 0):
            return -1

        # message is of the format "hello|2". Meaning message is "hello" from machine with id 2
        # However, the message received is processed and then returned back to the user
        message += '|' + str(self.get_id())

        machine.q[mac_id].put(message)
        return 1

    def recv(self):
        mac_id = self.get_id()
        if(mac_id >= machine.count.value or mac_id <= 0):
            return -1, -1

        message =  machine.q[mac_id].get().split('|')

        # message received is returned with the format "hello" message from "machine_2"
        return message[0], 'machine_' + message[1]

    def get_id(self):
        return self.mac_id

    def get_machine_id(self):
        return "machine_" + str(self.get_id())
```

You can assign tasks to each machine instance that you would create. These tasks are to be given in the form of a function. These functions are to be kept in a file in the same folder with name `functions.py`

Suppose I want 2 machine instances. One would send the other machine 10 numbers and the other one will return the sum. In this case, the functions would look something like this.

```
def machine1(id_var):
    print "machine instance started with id:", id_var.get_machine_id()

    # id_var.get_machine_id() is used to get the machine id

    for i in range(10):
        id_var.send("machine_2", str(i))

    message, sender = id_var.recv()

    print id_var.get_machine_id(), " got sum =", message, " from", sender

def machine2(id_var):
    print "machine instance started with id:", id_var.get_machine_id()

    # id_var.get_machine_id() is used to get the machine id

    total = 0
    for i in range(10):
        message, sender = id_var.recv()
        total += int(message)
    id_var.send("machine_1", str(total))
```

Now to run this, you need to create a machine instance and assign the proper function to it. Like

```
from dss import *

m1 = machine()
m1.execute_func("machine1")

m2 = machine()
m2.execute_func("machine2")
```

This all works fine. I am already using this library to implement some pretty complex distributed load balancing algorithms.

I'm looking for a review as to this being a good enough solution, or new features that should be added.

---

For more information, you can see the [github page](https://github.com/harisphnx/Distributed_Sytem_Simulator-DSS_py.git).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do these things as improvements:

- Follow PEP-8 and PEP-257 for writing code and docstrings in Python.
- Use the `configparser` module in Python to get config parameters
- Use `logging` module instead of `print`
- Compatibility Python2 and Python3, that means change every `try` ... `except Exception, e` and all the `print` statements.

Also I saw your config.txt file is repeated in two paths in your GitHub project.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions, I will certainly use all of them. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### [Avoid `exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707442/3105485)

It will take some major redesigning, but the resulting code will enjoy all of the benefits of not using `exec` listed above.

`Multiprocessing` can take first class functions as arguments, [see the docs for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707442/3105485).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have redesigned it and removed the use of exec. You can check it in github. If anything else can be changed to make it better, please do comment. :)